# insert into sql database using php

Tags: php, sql

I have been working on adding data to my sql database i have tryed many different ways of doing this but am still gettting the same errors.

Notice: Undefined index: ModuleId in N:\ftp\compc\d11os\Project\addModule.php on line 63

Notice: Undefined index: Title in N:\ftp\compc\d11os\Project\addModule.php on line 64

Notice: Undefined index: CreditLevel in N:\ftp\compc\d11os\Project\addModule.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined index: CreditPoints in N:\ftp\compc\d11os\Project\addModule.php on line 66

Notice: Undefined index: Status in N:\ftp\compc\d11os\Project\addModule.php on line 67

what am i doing wring i know it probly somthing smalll but i cant see it and really need help?

here is the code i am using

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","ROOT","ROOT","ROOTdb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$ModuleId = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['ModuleId']);
$Title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Title']);
$CreditLevel = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['CreditLevel']);
$CreditPoints = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['CreditPoints']);
$Status = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Status']);
$Award = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Award']);


$sql="INSERT INTO module(ModuleId, Title, CreditLevel, CreditPoints, Status, Award)
VALUES ('$ModuleId', '$Title', '$CreditLevel' ,'$CreditPoints', '$Status', '$Award')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Html code im using

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

        <img src="logo.jpg" alt="University of Ulster Logo" width="332" height="132">

    <h1 style="font-family:Bell MT;color:blue;font-size:28px;">Add a New Module.</h1>

</head>
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

 <table border="0">

  <tr><td>Module:</td><td>

 <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="60" required>

 </td></tr>

  <tr><td>Title:</td><td>

 <input type="text" name="telephoneNo" maxlength="60" required>

 </td></tr>

 <tr><td>CreditLevel:</td><td>

 <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="60" required>

 </td></tr>

 <tr><td>CreditPoints:</td><td>

 <input type="text" name="course" maxlength="60" required>

 </td></tr>

 <tr><td>Status:</td><td>

 <input type="text" name="Staus" maxlength="100" required>

 </td></tr>

  <tr><td>Award:</td><td>

 <input type="text" name="Award" maxlength="100" required>

 </td></tr>

 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
<input type="submit" name='submit' value='Submit'>

 </form>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` to check if it contains the indexes you expect it to contain

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index:...` means exactly that; the variable following is 'Undefined'.

Comment: A notice is not an error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is appearing because the variables you are using are not defined in the `$_POST` array.

Try something like

```
if (isset($_POST['ModuleId']))
{
    $ModuleId = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['ModuleId']);
} else {
    $ModuleId = -1; // Default value or Error flag
    echo "Module Id is not specified.";
}
```

and so on for your other variables.

It is probably a good idea to check that all the values are present, prior to insert.  For example,

```
if ($ModuleId != -1) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO module(ModuleId, Title, CreditLevel, CreditPoints, Status, Award)
    VALUES ('$ModuleId', '$Title', '$CreditLevel' ,'$CreditPoints', '$Status', '$Award')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

// EDIT

You issue seems to be stemming from not checking if the page has done a post back.  When the page is first loaded, it will try to insert data - but there is no data to insert as you have not submitted the form.

Wrap your php code with a simple check like so

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","ROOT","ROOT","ROOTdb");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    // escape variables for security
    $ModuleId = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['ModuleId']);
    $Title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Title']);
    $CreditLevel = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['CreditLevel']);
    $CreditPoints = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['CreditPoints']);
    $Status = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Status']);
    $Award = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Award']);


    $sql="INSERT INTO module(ModuleId, Title, CreditLevel, CreditPoints, Status, Award)
        VALUES ('$ModuleId', '$Title', '$CreditLevel' ,'$CreditPoints', '$Status', '$Award')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: the code i am using is adding a record to the sql table but it not adding the information i and typing it it is just adding in black Fields?

Comment: @user3605679 Update your question with the html, it is likely that the form is not submitting correctly, or using `GET` instead of `POST`.

Comment: @user3605679 i have added the html as requested

Comment: @user3605679 Thanks, I have updated the answer.  You need a simple check for form submission.

Comment: i have done that but know im getting a error "object not found"

Comment: @user3605679 you are missing something, I have typed out the code as it should look.

Comment: i have check this and still getting the object error would o=it have anythign till do with the following  <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?> method="post" >

Comment: @user3605679 The object required will give you a line number, work with that.  Also, that line should include an `echo` command - <?php echo $_PHP_SELF; ?>

Comment: i was missing a " ad the end of my post acusing the issue the form is now working and adding data to the database :)